# How do you connect two edge loops with a face between?

Tags: modeling, workflow, edges

[image: Here's a screenshot part of a nose]

If you notice there is a empty spot with no edge loop in between a line of edge loops. I am wondering if you can just add one edge loop in between that gap?

Answer (score 8):

There are several way of doing this.

- The easiest is to use the [vertex connect path tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/vertex_connect.html) <kbd>J</kbd> which will make a new edge between the two vertices, splitting the face into two.
- The next best thing would be to use the [knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html) <kbd>K</kbd> and just cut in new edge between the two vertices. Again that will take care of the faces.
- To use the fill tool <kbd>F</kbd> you will first have to delete the N-gon in the middle. Then create two faces.

In this gif I go through the three methods listed above. First using the vertex connect tool, then the knife tool, and last creating the two faces manually with the fill tool.
[image: animated gif showing how to add an Loop cut in a N-gon]

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Vertex Connect Path* operator, by default <kbd>J</kbd> key.

Select both loose vertex at opposite ends and press <kbd>J</kbd>.
[image: Vertex Connect Path]

Comment: Grr you beat me, but only because it took me 3 tries to record my gif. :) Have a UV.

Comment: Haha, it also took me a few tries to get right, have an upvote yourself :) Nice GIF BTW, more complete than mine.